# insert URLs in kunamed.bst

Tags: bibtex, lyx, bibliography

I am using LyX and would like to add URLs to my @misc entries in my bibtex bibliography. I am using the kunamed.bst style for my bibliography. My bibtex entries looks like this

```
@misc{RFA2011,
author = {RFA},
booktitle = {Statistics},
title = {{Renewable Fuels Association}},
url = {http://www.ethanolrfa.org/pages/statistics},
urldate = {Jan 13th 2014},
year = {2014}
}
```

I have tried to change the `FUNCTION {misc}` in the kunamed.bst file like from this:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  output.year.check
  format.title output
  format.date output
  new.block
  howpublished output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

to this

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  output.year.check
  format.title output
  format.date output
  format.url output % <------
  new.block
  howpublished output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

No change is happening in my bibliography. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This might be better placed at tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by changing the way the url is written in the bibtex entry

```
@misc{RFA2011,
author = {RFA},
booktitle = {Statistics},
title = {{Renewable Fuels Association}},
howpublished = "\url{http://www.ethanolrfa.org/pages/statistics}", % <---
year = {2014},
note = "[Accessed online: 13-Jan-2014]"
```